# Compressible Fluid - Incompressible fluid - Density

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

Imagine you have a perfect container (adiabatic system) and within the container you have two fluids. Fluid 1 is a compressible gas. Fluid 2 is an incompressible liquid.

We start increasing the amount of Fluid 2 within the container which compresses Fluid 1. What happens to the density of the compressible gas? See concept image below.

[image: Concept Image]

Conceptually I believe that the density of the compressible fluid would approach that of the incompressible fluid. But I'm not sure what governing equation would dictate this. I would estimate the relationship would look like an asymptotic approach to Fluid's 2 density as the pressure rises to infinity.

[image: Relationship]

Comment: The incompressible fluid scenario is exactly the same as a cylinder with a piston that can move (see any thermodynamics textbook for more details). The *pressure* in the two fluids is the same. The *density* of the compressible fluid can be anything, depending on its equation of state (e.g. the ideal gas law).  In any case the question is hypothetical, because there are no real incompressible fluids. (The question also ignores the fact that one fluid may partially or completely dissolve in the other, etc, etc...)

Comment: Great point comparing it to a solid piston. I suppose it makes sense to compare incompressible liquids to solids. What happens when we do consider Fluid 2 compressibility? I guess in that instance the fluids would converge until the density separation between the fluids is non-existent?

Comment: If both materials are compressible, they will change their volume to minimize the total energy of the system.